# Pass data via AJAX onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user clicks a certain link, I'd like to run an AJAX call that sets a  `$_SESSION` variable, while still directing the user towards the link's `href`.

When I run the following code, Firebug shows that there is an error, but doesn't specify; `readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"` is all I get from `console.log`.

If I add `e.preventDefault` and `window.location.href = linkPath;` into my `success` function, the script sends the user to the correct place; but only after a delay while it waits for the php page to complete.

How can I run the AJAX call while still passing the user through to their link without delay?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".example_class").click(function(e) {
    //Stop the page from leaving until we start our ajax
    //e.preventDefault();

    //var linkPath = this.href;

    var form_data = new Object();

    //Set the application ID for insert into the DB
    form_data.variableName = encodeURIComponent('ExampleName');

    //Send the data out to be processed and stored
    $.ajax({
       url:'/mypath/myfile.php',
       type:'POST',
       data:form_data,
       success:function(return_data){
            //window.location.href = linkPath;
            return;
        },
       error:function(w,t,f){
           console.log(w);
           return;
       }
    }); 

    return;
});
});
```

Comment: You can't. The browser needs to complete the request to set the session variable, and if you leave the page right away it won't have time to do so.

Comment: @adeneo I thought that if the AJAX calls the myfile.php, it doesn't matter if the browser leaves the page before the `success` function can be run, myfile.php has already started running on the server and will finish running to the end of file. Essentially, its the server that is running myfile.php not the browser. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: I confirm, you can't. When you quit your page, all requests are cancelled

Comment: @adeneo The object of this is the link is a "Give" link that goes to a information page about how to give, and I wanted to track if they actually go through and give, that it came from this link. As an alternative, is it proper/efficient to send them to myfile.php?mylink=yes, process that URL param on myfile.php, then refresh the page without the URL parameter, so that if they share the link, they aren't sharing myfile.php?mylink=yes and messing up my stats.

Comment: You are sort of right. If the request is sent to the server, then  it does'nt matter if you wait for the success callback or not. The problem is that only way to know that the browser had time to send the request is to wait for an answer back in the success callback before redirecting. In some browsers, and sometimes, the ajax request will be sent even if you redirect right away, but it's not consistent, and it does'nt matter if you bind to onbeforeunload (unless you do the ajax synchronously, which is even worse), the only way to make sure it was received serverside is to wait for a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in coments, ajax calls are aborted when the caller page is unloaded. 
But it does not mean that the server has not  received the call, it only means that the server has not sent back a reply. 
To minimize the time spent by the ajax call, you could just wait for the first response to the ajax call with "xhr.onprogress" (which is not implemented in $.ajax from jquery), and then open the link.

But, if you were having the control of the server, simply make a redirection of '/mypath/myfile.php?redirect_url='+linkPath to linkPath with:

```
header('location: '.$_GET['redirect_url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the ajax call, then redirect the user. The ajax call will send before the window.location changes. The only thing you can't account for is if the ajax call fails.

```
$(".example_class").click(function(e) {
    var linkPath = this.href; 
    var form_data = new Object();

    //Set the application ID for insert into the DB
    form_data.variableName = encodeURIComponent('ExampleName');

    //Send the data out to be processed and stored
    $.ajax({
       url:'/mypath/myfile.php',
       type:'POST',
       data:form_data,
       success:function(data){ alert('never alerts but request sent to server.'); },
       error:function(){  alert('page changes, but ajax request failed, sorry.'); }
    });
    window.location.href = linkPath;
    return;
});
```

The other option is to set the [onbeforeunload event](http://upshots.org/javascript/window-onbeforeunload) with an ajax call.

Comment: My first try was the code you wrote, and it produces the same error message.

Comment: Yeah, this is super wrong. You could put an async:false in that ajax call, but then you come across the same issue OP originally dealt with.